EntraID Guest External Users are not adding as a new user, but rather as a proxy to a current Guest External User
When adding a Guest External user to EntraID, e.g. a@a.com, the user is not added but the email address a@a.com goes onto the proxyAddress of another Guest External user with email address b@a.com.
We have many external users from the same company using the same domain email that we need to invite.
We initially thought we fixed it by:

Soft-delete the user with the bad proxyAddress. Example: b@a.com
Adding the new guest external user e.g. a@a.com
Using

Connect-MsolService

Restore-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName b@a.com -AutoReconcileProxyConflicts




But the third user then got added to the proxyAddress of the second user, so we deleted the second user, and tried to add it again, but it got added to the first user...
In the end our only way to make it work was:

Delete any current external user(s) using the domain e.g. b.com

Create the new guest external user in EntraID

Delete the new guest external user in EntraID

Go through and do step 2 and 3 for all users being added from b.com

After all users have been added and deleted open PowerShell and run the following for each of the deleted users:

Install-Module MSOnline

Connect-MsolService

Restore-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <user>@<domain> -AutoReconcileProxyConflicts




Has anyone got a proper fix for this, as their next new hire will cause us to go through the entire process again?
